# RestController - Use @DateTimeFormat inside deserialized POJO

Tags: java, spring, datetime, spring-restcontroller

I have JSON body with date parameters that I need to deserialized

Following [Working with Date Parameters in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters)

> annotate the parameters with the @DateTimeFormat annotation and provide a formatting pattern parameter:
>
> We can also use our own conversion patterns. We can just provide a pattern parameter in the @DateTimeFormat annotation:
>
> ```
> @PostMapping("/date")
> public void date(@RequestParam("date") 
>    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date date) {
> ```

I created a POJO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestVO {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Date startDate;
```

My RestController endpoint

```
@PostMapping(value = "path", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String updateDate(RequestVO requestVO) {
        logger.debug("requestVO.getStartDate()=" + requestVO.getStartDate());
```

I POST data:

```
{"startDate":"11.11.2019 11:11:11"}
```

But my startDate is null

- Other parameters are working fine (except date)

Can I use `@DateTimeFormat` inside Object or must I declare all parameters as in example?

Comment: Try changing `Date` to `LocalDateTime`

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Unfortunately same result with `LocalDateTime`

Comment: on your restController, try to add @RequestBody before RequestVO
`updateDate(@RequestBody RequestVO requestVO) {`

Comment: have you tried it or not @user7294900

Comment: @NaFelixWimpyWijaya yes, see comment to avi answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try @JsonDeserialize

```
 @JsonDeserialize(using = DateHandler.class)
  private Date publicationDate;
```

DateHandler  class

```
class DateHandler extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

  public DateHandler() {
    this(null);
  }

  public DateHandler(Class<?> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException {
    String date = jsonparser.getText();
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      return sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

For reference [How to deserialize Date from JSON using Jackson](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-date-field-in-java-jackson-example.html)

Comment: first option is my question and second is @NikNik answer which didn't helped

Comment: Try custom serialize @JsonDeserialize

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `@RequestBody` in the controller, so the value is considered as `QueryParam`. Add, it will work.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "path", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String updateDate(@RequestBody RequestVO requestVO) { // Added Request Body
        logger.debug("requestVO.getStartDate()=" + requestVO.getStartDate());
}
```

Another thing I noticed is the date format `"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"`, I think this is not a Valid format of `DateTimeFormatter`

#### Valid Formats

> `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"`

`Note : Might have missed some Formats but if any do edit it will be helpful to all`

### UPDATE

If you don't want millisec I think `@DateTimeFormat` won't help you, go with `@JsonFormat` like others suggested.But You should change the format of the request body like

```
{
 "startDate":"2019-11-11 11:11:11"
}
```

and the change in class will be

```java
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 Date startDate;
```

Have also looked into formats `SimpleDateFormat` (`@JsonFormat` use this foramtter), refer [SimpleDateFormat - Patterns](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html)

Comment: It worked with different (valid) format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z` but can't I changed it? I don't need miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private Date start;
```

and change the desired format

Comment: It didn't work, should I kept the `@DateTimeFormat` also?