# @DateTimeFormat doesn't return any binding result error in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to validate a date field with specific date format ("yyyy-MM-dd"). I guess it's validating the date format correctly, but the problem is i'm getting a blank response if it's invalid. Please suggest me some solutions.

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateProject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ApiResponse updateProject(@Valid @RequestBody ProjectModel model, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        return projectService.updateProject(model); 
    }

// Validation Response
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    System.out.println("ERROR OCCURED");
    ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse(status.value(),ex.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage(),"");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

**Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT_MODEL")
public class ProjectModel {

    @Column(name="EXPECTED_END_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE, pattern= "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    LocalDate expectedEndDate;

       // getter - setter
}
```

I Have also create a file in resource folder message.properties

```
typeMismatch=Invalid date format. Please use yyyy/MM/dd.
```

I Have attached the response images below.

[1. With valid date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtavZ.png)

[2. With invalid date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBHdr.png)

[3. With Other invalid fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAUQg.png)

Comment: Does it work for you for any other invalid field ?:>

Comment: Yes, it is working for other invalid fields

Comment: 2 and 3 got response code 400 ?

Comment: Yes, But in 2 response body is blank

Comment: Most probabaly different method of https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html is called.

Comment: Ok, let me try using controllerAdvice class

Comment: Yes, @Antoniossss a different method was called, you are right. Put that as an answer i shall accept it. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. Answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probabaly different method of [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) is called.

Comment: After trying I found this method of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler is called handleTypeMismatch or handleExceptionInternal if the first handle is not implemented

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766345/restcontroller-use-datetimeformat-inside-deserialized-pojo) DateTimeFormat and JsonFormat was ignored

It was fixed only by using specific  `@JsonDeserialize` for field

> ```
> @JsonDeserialize(using = DateHandler.class)
> private Date publicationDate;
>
> class DateHandler extends StdDeserializer<Date> {
>
>  public DateHandler() {
>     this(null);
>   }
>
>  public DateHandler(Class<?> clazz) {
>     super(clazz);
>   }
>
>  @Override
>   public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
>       throws IOException {
>     String date = jsonparser.getText();
>     try {
>       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
>       return sdf.parse(date);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>       return null;
>     }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Using this, It's not validating the date. Because i guess from catch block it is returning null and the same is being stored in db.

Comment: @sam yes, you need to change the catch in your case

Comment: I need to send the response back if there is an invalid date. There is no validation happening here